# Regex need 4 numeric characters

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm editing password rules and the previous requirement looked like the following:

```
-- Contain characters from the following four (4) categories:
-- English uppercase characters (A through Z)
-- English lowercase characters (a through z)
-- Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
-- Non-alphabetic characters (for example: !, $, %)

SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), 1, '((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])).*', 'Password Rule 3', true;
```

The new rule is just that I need 4 numeric characters and the rest can be anything. I am trying the following:

```
SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), 1, '((?=.*\d{4,})(?=.*[\W_])).*', 'Password Rule 3', true;
```

But when I insert this into the database and try to make a new account with the password rules it generates errors. Is this a regex problem? If the regex is good then its just a separate database problem that I'll have to sort out.

Comment: What do you mean by 4 numeric characters? Should they be consecutive or not? What about the rest of requirements, are they no longer valid?

Comment: the password just needs 4 numeric characters (0-9). Any order is fine and the rest of the password can be any combination of characters, numbers, and symbols. The other requirements are no longer valid

Comment: Then use `'(?:\D*\d){4}'` or `'(?:\D*\d){4}.*'`

Comment: Thanks that works well in the regex tester. The one I was using wasn't actually working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), 1, '(?:\D*\d){4}', 'Password Rule 3', true;
```

The regex will match four occurrences of any chars other than digits followed with a digit.

In effect, this pattern requires a string to contain any four not necessarily consecutive digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yc2ieV/1).